# How do I post a screenshot from Mac OS X Lion on askdifferent?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, screen-capture, utilities

How do I take a screenshot?  On the other Mac I was using, grab was installed, but paying for screenshots seems excessive.

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version:   Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 11.4.2
  Boot Volume:  Untitled
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:    a MacBook
  User Name:    thufir (thufir)
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No
  Time since boot:  53 minutes
```

More specifically, how do I post that screenshot here on askdifferent?

I see that you can **[take](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph11229?locale=en_US)** a screenshot...but...where is it saved?

Comment: The first sentence of your link reads "Pictures of the screen (screenshots) are saved as files on the desktop"

Comment: Grab is part of the OS X install so no need to pay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To take a screenshot of the full screen hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>.
- To take a screenshot of a part of the screen hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>. You'll get a crosshair, click the mouse button to define the first corner, hold the button, move the cursor and then release it to define the transverse corner. The grey overlay spanning between the two corners will be the screenshot.
- To take a screenshot of a special window hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> then the spacebar and choose the window with a symbolic camera.

The default location for saved screenshots taken this way is on the **Desktop**.

To change the default location enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /path/;killall SystemUIServer
```

Example:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Pictures/
```

Hit the return key to set ~/Pictures as the location. You’ll need to follow it up with a SystemUIServer relaunch too:

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

If you want to save them in a new folder create a new folder first with

```
mkdir ~/Screenshots
```

---

To upload it hit the symbol pic (with the red circle in my screenshot) and choose your screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MacBook Air, the easiest way I have found (and the only way) is to press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> then select 'Options' and you will there be able to choose where to save it. Before you select where you want to save them, they will - if I am correct - save to Desktop. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -1):

To your other question, to add a screenshot, screen recording or any video/picture file follow these steps:

1. Click 'Edit Question' if you have already published your question (if you haven't published your question already, just move to step 2)
2. There should be a picture of 2 mountains and a dot for a sun (in black and white) in the top of the box where your writing your question.
3. Email the screenshot or picture/video file you wish to upload to the mac that you are using AskDifferent on
4. Save the emailed picture/video or screenshot file to your laptop somewhere
5. Click on this button and it will let you upload a screenshot or picture/video file
6. Find the screenshot or picture/video file you wish to upload and click 'Open'
7. Your question will contain a link to your photo - if anybody clicks on this link they will see your screenshot or photo/video file
   Hope this helps

Comment: Also you can screen reccord and heaps of other screenshot options by clicking Command + Shift + 5